# How to split array in php with 2 strings?

Tags: php, arrays

How to split array with `,` in 2 parts so that that can be used as 2 strings in php?

I am getting this kind of array you can view image with this list.
I want to split this array to post id and title in separate columns.

```
<li  id="recordsArray_'.$value['id'].','.$value['title'].'"></li>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your sample array as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try with below code if it works for you

```
$arr = array('1,test1','2,test2','3,test3');

foreach($arr as $ar){
  $res = explode(',', $ar);
  $id = $res[0];
  $title = $res[1]; 

  echo 'id-'.$id;
  echo ' title-'.$title;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate array into two string, you can use explode like this short code:

```
$item = '4,test';
$var = explode(',', $item);
echo $var;
```

and for loop array, you can use

```
$array = array(YOUR_ARRAY);
foreach($array as $item){
    $var = explode(',', $item);
    echo $var;
}
```

**Update 1:**
You can use a simple array like below code:

```
$array = array(4, 'salar');
```

and use a code like this:

```
$array = array(4, 'salar');
foreach ($array as $item) {
    dump(explode(',', $item));
}
```

Comment: it show me waring `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,array given in`